# How Do I Permanently Append To Python's sys.path

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

I'm trying to import some of my own modules on my mac and I can't figure out how to add the path to my modules. I have tried editing the PYTHONPATH environment variable, (`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/modules`) appending the path to sys.path, etc. Nothing seems to work for me. I want the path to be in sys.path permanently so that I don't need to keep putting `import sys` then `sys.path.append("/path/to/modules")` at the top of every document that I make. Is there a file somewhere that contains the path that I could edit? Or do I need to enter a command into terminal or something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use a `setup.py` to install the package to site packages instead of messing with the pythonpath, that way you can also install it in virtual envs.

Comment: There are sooo many things to say, here, but firstly, make certain that you are using `venv` appropriate for your python version. Then, you should be able to add to the `.env` that you source going into the project directory such that you get a viable PYTHONPATH. Hacking sys path for the whole mac will eventually bring you much sadness ....

Comment: Ok. In response to T4rk1n, where would I find the setup.py file? I've run a search over the whole computer and all that I found were setup files for other modules

Comment: There is none, you have to write it: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: Ok. Where do I save the setup file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "install" modules, yes, create a site package. If you just doing something locally, for fun / education on you own computer, modify PYTHONPATH.

On a Mac, you're most likely using `bash` as your shell.

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/modules:${PYTHONPATH}
export PYTHONPATH
```

...will do what you want in your current shell. To make it permanent (for you), add both lines to your local `.bashrc` file, under your home directory.

If you want to make it permanent for all users of this computer.. don't edit the systemwide `/etc/profile` -- that's when you really should install it correctly using packages.

Comment: Ok. So how do I edit the .bashrc file and where do I put those two lines?

Comment: Never mind the how. I figured that out. Should I just put those lines at the end of the file?

Comment: yes, end of file, beginning of file.... To verify it's the right file and correct edit. login / login and then `echo $PYTHONPATH`. On a Mac, normally it's empty.